# Android: How do I display an updating clock in a TextView

Tags: android, timer, clock

have a clock I want to display in a TextView.

I would have thought there was a few nice functions to do this, but I couldn't find anything.
I ended up implementing my own way that uses a Handler. What I'm asking though, is there a better (more efficient) way to display a real time updating clock?

```
private Runnable mUpdateClockTask = new Runnable() {
   public void run() {
       setTime();
       mClockHandler.postDelayed(this, 1000);
   }
};
```

That's my handler, which runs every second, and then my set time and date function is below

```
TextView mClockView;

public void setTime() {
    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    int minutes = cal.get(Calendar.MINUTE);

    if (DateFormat.is24HourFormat(this)) {
        int hours = cal.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
        mClockView.setText((hours < 10 ? "0" + hours : hours) + ":" + (minutes < 10 ? "0" + minutes : minutes));
    }
    else {
        int hours = cal.get(Calendar.HOUR);
        mClockView.setText(hours + ":" + (minutes < 10 ? "0" + minutes : minutes) + " " + new DateFormatSymbols().getAmPmStrings()[cal.get(Calendar.AM_PM)]);
    }
}
```

Cheers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remember: premature optimization is the root of all evil. So only optimize when you are sure (=have measured it) that your implementation is slow/inefficient.

That said, a more efficient method would probably be to record start time via `System.currentTimeMillis()` and then periodically check it and calculate difference in minutes.

Comment: Hmm, that's a good idea. Furthermore - once I know the current seconds until the next update, then I only need to call my handler after that many seconds.

Comment: In general you are right that premature optimization is bad, but the implementation in the OP really is very bad, starting a new thread every second, and the optimization you offer completely ignores that and offers an optimization that will probably indeed not make a noticeable difference.

Answer (score 50):

Updating the system clock is not like updating a chronometer. We talk about the time changed **on the minute** (system clock minute and 00 seconds).

Using a Timer is not the right way to do this. It's not only overkill, but you must resort to some tricks to make it right.

The right way to do this (ie. update a TextView showing the time as HH:mm) is to use BroadcastReceiver like this :

```
BroadcastReceiver _broadcastReceiver;
private final SimpleDateFormat _sdfWatchTime = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm");
private TextView _tvTime;

@Override
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    _broadcastReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
            @Override
            public void onReceive(Context ctx, Intent intent) {
                if (intent.getAction().compareTo(Intent.ACTION_TIME_TICK) == 0)
                    _tvTime.setText(_sdfWatchTime.format(new Date()));
            }
        };

    registerReceiver(_broadcastReceiver, new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_TIME_TICK));
}

@Override
public void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    if (_broadcastReceiver != null)
        unregisterReceiver(_broadcastReceiver);
}
```

The system will send this broadcast event at the exact beginning of every minutes based on system clock. Don't forget however to initialize your TextView beforehand (to current system time) since it is likely you will pop your UI in the middle of a minute and the TextView won't be updated until the next minute happens.

Comment: That worked for me. Thank you! Too bad though that you can't have the same kind of broadcast for the second, but I understand the underlying reason.

Comment: Yes. I guess that if you need to show seconds, you may use a repeating Timer or something similar. As long as it is re-synchronized every minute to make sure it remain correct in the long run, it should be ok. But using a Timer for the whole thing is just plain wrong. It is a subtle point most people don't see as it seems almost correct, but it's not (except if you do additional stuffs which are overall heavier than using ACTION_TIME_TICK broadcast).

Comment: @Alex Can you please let me know what `if (intent.getAction().compareTo(Intent.ACTION_TIME_TICK) == 0)` means?

Comment: It checks that the received event is the intended one. It is useless in this case since the receiver can only receive that event (IntentFilter says so during registration). Still, this is a good habit and only here for completeness.

Comment: @Alex Very nice explanation with fantastic example. Thank you so much for example and explanation. You save my lots of time.

Answer (score 16):

Check out the [Chronometer](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Chronometer.html) and [DigitalClock](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/DigitalClock.html) classes, which are extensions of the TextView class. They should automatically do what you're looking for. If you need some additional functionality, just take a look at the source code for those and make any changes you need.

UPDATE:

Since digital clock is deprecated in API 17, I would recommend to use [Text Clock](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextClock.html)  instead.

Comment: DigitalClock doesn't give the flexibility of being able to specify a format. Which doesn't do what I need. Also I tried Chronometer but it didn't seem to want to play nice. Thanks though!

Comment: I understand there are limitations, which is why I suggested grabbing the [source code](http://www.google.com/codesearch#uX1GffpyOZk/core/java/android/widget/Chronometer.java) and making alterations as needed. I've also had limitations using the Chronometer and was able to just copy the code and make the necessary changes.

Comment: DigitalClock seems to be deprecated. Use [TextClock](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextClock.html) instead ([source code](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/master/core/java/android/widget/TextClock.java)).

Answer (score 10):

I recommend [TextClock](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextClock.html) (From API 17), also please dont use DigitalClock (Deprecated from API 17) as it will cause MEMORY LEAK and will lead to Out of Memory Exception.
Please add the following piece of code to corresponding layout.xml file

```
 <TextClock
   android:id="@+id/textClock1"
   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:gravity="center_horizontal"
   android:textColor="#17d409" />
```

This will do the trick, also please note that you can format the displaying time as required for example for getting in 12 hour format with seconds you can use "android:format12Hour="hh:mm:ss a"".

Comment: Please elaborate your answers with the help of some code example. Otherwise it will be no use for readers

Comment: @MuhammadHaseebKhan short Google search for "android TextClock" will take anyone to an example page which basically says: just put TextClock view inside your layout.xml file. I voted up for this answer.

Answer (score 3):

You can use TextClock widget provided by android

```
<TextClock
    android:id="@+id/textClock"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:format12Hour="hh:mm:ss a"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:textColor="#d41709"
    android:textSize="20sp"
    android:textStyle="bold" />
```

it requires minimum API level 17

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextClock

if you want the current time in another text view

you can use the below code snippet

```
 tClock = (TextClock) findViewById(R.id.textClock1);
        tView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textview1);
        btn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnGet);
        btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                tView.setText("Time: "+tClock.getText());
            }
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

DigitalClock widget is available in android api 1 or use TextClock widget in api 17

create layout for clock like this first:

```
<LinearLayout 
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    >
    <TextView android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:id="@+id/clocktext"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
        android:textSize="50sp"
        android:text="2:46"/>
    <DigitalClock android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:id="@+id/clock"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textSize="50sp"
        android:visibility="gone"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        />  
    </LinearLayout>
```

in Activity add textchage listener to the DigitalClock its a subclass of textview thus we can add textchangedkistener to get the updated time and set the time to your textview as you want

```
chagre = (TextView) mTopView.findViewById(R.id.clocktext);// TextView to display Time
    clock = (DigitalClock) mTopView.findViewById(R.id.clock);// DigitalClock With visibility=gone

    clock.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before,
                int count) {}

        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
                int after) {}
        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

            chagre.setText(s.toString());//will be called when system clock updataes

        }
    });
```

Comment: DigitalClock is now deprecated since API 17