# Updating clock in Android

Tags: java, android

I'm searching for the easiest solution to implement a self updating digital clock in Android. I know that there is already digital clock class: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/DigitalClock.html
and yes it's also deprecated. From API 17 we now use TextClock. Anyways for the sake of learning i want to make my own custom clock showing hh:mm:ss and of course should updating itself.

So far i make reference to my textview ( where digital clock will be displayed ), and i got instance of Calendar class and i also sign minutes, hours and seconds to instance variables:

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
            hour = cal.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
            min = cal.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
            sec = cal.get(Calendar.SECOND);
                clock.setText(hour+":"+min+":"+sec);
```

If i run this code, the accurate time is displayed on emulator but obviously it's not updating. What i must do, so my code will "looping" and updating my clock?

I already checked this nice answer: [Android: How do I display an updating clock in a TextView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7363119/android-how-do-i-display-an-updating-clock-in-a-textview) but my question is: I want the easiest solution of digital clock in android =) Do i still need to use Handler?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well using a [Handler](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html) isn't that difficult. One possible implementation is (note: I didn't check if it leaks or not):

```
final Handler h = new Handler();
h.post(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        updateTime();
        h.postDelayed(this, 1000);
    }
});
```

If you don't want to use Handler, you could also use a [CountDownTimer](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/CountDownTimer.html) with `millisInFuture` set to `Long.MAX_VALUE`. But this is really a hack and I don't know if Android implementation can handle the integer overflow correctly.

Comment: Good answer.. i'm satisfied.

Comment: I'm getting back after 8 years when I earned the "badge" for this question. Well, 8 years after I'm still learning to code. xD

Answer (score 0):

Since you cannot "loop" on the main (UI) thread, you need to use another mechanism to "update" your UI every so often. You can use a Handler, a TimerTask, a Thread or some other mechanism that allows you to schedule something to happen in the future.