# Android: how do i call and execute a method at any time but under condition (without any click)

Tags: java, android

simply, my app has a textview and digitalclock
i want to know how can i run a method when 
the text of textview isequal the text of digitalclock

```
TextView txt = (TextView) findViewBuId(R.id.text);
DigitalClock clc = (DigitalClock) findViewBuId(R.id.Clock);

if(txt.getText().iseqaul(clc.getText.toString))
{//my code}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well seeing as how DigitalClock appears to be deprecated I Found this link.  [Android: How do I display an updating clock in a TextView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7363119/android-how-do-i-display-an-updating-clock-in-a-textview).  The answer by alex shows how to display the clock time and it updates, also you get the notice on each time update so you can do that check for equals there and do essentially what you want to do.  Just change from digitalclock to a textview and let it update like digital clock.

Answer (score 0):

One way you can do it is implementing Observer Design Pattern, this will allow you to listen for event or conditions that you have to register for. You can find reference of that [here](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/design_pattern/)

I hope this help