# android how to increment seconds in date time text view

Tags: android, datetime, timertask

i have a textview having a specific date time string as this format dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss. I need to create a thread that increment number of second in the textview every one second so its update : minutes, day, month year....
how to create this handler ?

so the text view will updated every 1 sec according to first time displayed in the text view
example if the textview display : 06/03/2017 01:20:00 it will be updated as below every second
06/03/2017 01:20:01
06/03/2017 01:20:02
06/03/2017 01:20:03
06/03/2017 01:20:04
06/03/2017 01:20:05
06/03/2017 01:20:06
.
.
.
.
.
06/03/2017 01:21:00

Comment: This might help you - http://stackoverflow.com/a/14512130/3765646

Comment: Is your question how to format a text to date/time or how to execute a UI operation every second?

Comment: how to format a date time text view

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve from

```
int timeinminutes=1;

timer = new CountDownTimer(timeinminutes*21000, 1000) 
{

    TextView jeutimer = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.jeu_timer);

     public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) 
     {
         long scnds=0;
         scnds=(millisUntilFinished/1000);
         jeutimer.setText( "" + scnds);        // Add your date here..
     }


     public void onFinish() 
     {

     }
```

}.start();

Now you will be able to restart it whenever you want with:

```
timer.start();
```

And stop it with:

```
timer.cancel();
```

**Edited**
You can also use this ..

```
txtView.setText(parseDate("06/03/2017 01:20:00","dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss","dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss"));

public static String parseDate(String Date, String CurrentPattern, String OutputPattern) {

    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat(CurrentPattern, Locale.getDefault());

    try {
        Date startDate = increaseDate(sdf.parse(Date));
        sdf.applyPattern(OutputPattern);
        return sdf.format(startDate);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        return "";
    }
}

public static Date increaseDate(Date origDate) {

    final Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();

    calendar.setTime(origDate);
    calendar.add(Calendar.SECONDS, +1);
    Date newDate = calendar.getTime();
    return newDate;
}
```

Comment: i want to start from the date displayed in the text view, i have this date returned by a web service

Comment: at first launch, the text view must display this date :06/03/2017 01:20:00. so i want to start increment seconds starting from this date

Comment: ohhk then first time you can set as usual and second time you want to increase from previous date.. right..?

Comment: if you achieve your goal then please tick to right my answer.. @Amalo

Answer (score 0):

[TextClock](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextClock.html) added in API Level 17.

Answer (score 0):

you can use handler for this, have a look at this [chronometer source](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/2.0_r1/android/widget/Chronometer.java#Chronometer.updateRunning%28%29)