# How to display and check date and time in Java on Android Studio?

Tags: java, android, datetime, time

I'm quite new to Java and Android Studio, and I'm trying to write a program where when a button is pressed during a specified time period of a day, an event occurs (such as displaying a textview). I am currently trying to display the time for the user to see, but the code does not seem to keep running, and only reflect the time when I last updated my app, and not displaying the time in real time.

```
Calendar calender = Calendar.getInstance();
System.out.println("Current time => "+calender.getTime());
SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss");
String formattedDate = df.format(calender.getTime());
dateandtimeTextView.setText("" +formattedDate);
```

Is there a way to have the time update continually like a normal clock?

Comment: As an aside consider throwing away the long outmoded and notoriously troublesome `SimpleDateFormat` and friends, and adding [ThreeTenABP](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) to your Android project in order to use `java.time`, the modern Java date and time API. It is so much nicer to work with.

Answer (score 1):

### Read the clock *when* you need the time

You need to read the system clock *when* the user presses the button, not once and for all when your app is launched. So put your call to `ZonedDateTime.now()`or `Calendar.getInstance()` or which means you are using for that *inside* the event handler that handles the button click and displays the time to the user.

The date/time object that you get from your call gets the time of when it was created and keeps that time. This is probably why you saw the time when you last updated your app. To get a new time on the next button press, you need to create a new date/time object.

### java.time and ThreeTenABP

BTW the `Calendar` class is poorly designed and long outdated. Here⁄s the modern way to get the current time:

```
    DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter
            .ofLocalizedDateTime(FormatStyle.MEDIUM)
            .withLocale(Locale.getDefault(Locale.Category.FORMAT));

    ZonedDateTime dateTime = ZonedDateTime.now(ZoneId.systemDefault());

    String formattedDate = dateTime.format(formatter);
    System.out.println(formattedDate);
```

The exact output from my snippet depends not only on the time, on the device locale too. In one instance I got the following output from running in English locale:

> Dec 7, 2019 2:38:04 PM

You may create the formatter once and for all, but you need to create `dateTime` every time. Instead of `Calendar` and `SimpleDateFormat` I am using java.time, the modern Java date and time API. It is so much nicer to work with.

To check whether we’re within some specified time period of the day, use `dateTime.toLocalTime()` and compare the result to `LocalTime` objects representing start and end of that period. `LocalTime` has methods `isBefore` and `isAfter`. You need one or both of those for the comparisons.

### Question: Doesn’t java.time require Android API level 26?

java.time works nicely on both older and newer Android devices. It just requires at least **Java 6**.

- In Java 8 and later and on newer Android devices (from API level 26) the modern API comes built-in.
- In non-Android Java 6 and 7 get the ThreeTen Backport, the backport of the modern classes (ThreeTen for JSR 310; see the links at the bottom).
- On (older) Android use the Android edition of ThreeTen Backport. It’s called ThreeTenABP. And make sure you import the date and time classes from `org.threeten.bp` with subpackages.

### Links

- [Oracle tutorial: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/) explaining how to use java.time.
- [Java Specification Request (JSR) 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310), where `java.time` was first described.
- [ThreeTen Backport project](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/), the backport of `java.time` to Java 6 and 7 (ThreeTen for JSR-310).
- [ThreeTenABP](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP), Android edition of ThreeTen Backport
- [Question: How to use ThreeTenABP in Android Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38922754/how-to-use-threetenabp-in-android-project), with a very thorough explanation.

Comment: I tried using the code you provided, but I still face the problem where whenever I launch the app, it displays the time when it launches. I want it to display the time as it passes, like a clock.. Also I was using the calander function because the older posts similar to my questions used that, the posts must have been there for a while now.

Comment: That has been asked and answered a number of times before. See for example [Android: How do I display an updating clock in a TextView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7363119/android-how-do-i-display-an-updating-clock-in-a-textview). Search for more.

Answer (score 0):

Try these two lines to get current date and time.

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy.MM.dd G 'at' HH:mm:ss z");
String currentDateandTime = sdf.format(new Date());
```

You also can refer to this link:
https://www.tutorialspoint.com/get-current-time-and-date-on-android

Comment: Thanks for wanting to contribute. Your format pattern is different from the one in the question. Is there any other difference? Do you seriously think that this will solve the problem asked about, displaying the time in real time? Asking because I’m pretty convinced that it will not.

Comment: ya ,i want to try to solve your problem,but my mistake on understanding the your question
so sorry.

Comment: You are using terrible date-time classes that were supplanted years ago by the modern *java.time* classes defined in JSR 310.